# Database Insertion not working with partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

i created one mvc application to show event details in a particular month.

i created one view which includes one jquery table(employee) having one ajax actionlink in each row. when we clicks each row one partial view will show which include one fullcalendar for each employee.

in that calendar we allot new event for each employee

the problem is

the event is saving successfully for the first employee but when we select any other link (different employee) the particular calendar will load but on saving it will show one error like

"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

my mainview (table creation)

```
function loadData(data) {

            var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
            var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
            thead.append('<th>Id</th><th></th>');
            thead.append('<th>Username</th>');
            tab.append(thead);
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empID + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' +"" + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td>' + val.empName + '</td>');
              var url = '@Url.Action("test", "Home", new { id = -1 })';
              url = url.replace('-1', val.empID);
              var anchor = '<a class="myClass" href="' + url + '">Edit</a>'
              trow.append('<td>' + anchor + '</td>');
             tab.append(trow);
            });
            $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
            $("#AllEmployees").html(tab);
        };
    $(document).on('click', '.myClass', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        //Code to load your partial view
        $('#calendar').load(this.href);
    });
```

partial view (project allocation happens here)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

                     //calendar will  show
                     //on button save
                      $('#btnPopupSave').click(function () {

            $('#popupEventForm').hide();

            var dataRow = {
                'userID': empid,
                'proID': "a2",
                'year': year,
                'start': st,
                'end': en
            }


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/SaveEvent",
                data: dataRow,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'True') {



                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert('New event saved!');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error, could not save event!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
                      });
```

controller

```
public bool SaveEvent(string userID, string proID, string year, string start, string end)
    {

        return AllottedDetails.AllotEmployee(userID,proID, year, start, end);
    }
```

class

```
public static bool AllotEmployee(string userID, string proID, string year, string start, string end)
    {
        string err;
        try
        {
            EMPAllocationDBEntities ent = new EMPAllocationDBEntities();
            ProjectAllocationDetail rec = new ProjectAllocationDetail();
            rec.UserId = Int32.Parse(userID);
            rec.ProjectId = proID;
            rec.Year = year;

            rec.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(start);
            rec.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(end);

            ent.ProjectAllocationDetails.Add(rec);
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

the code works fine for first employee in the table but if we select any other employee and try to allot project it show the error. i debuged the code and the data is coming correctly up to the class but on insertion its makes error.

please help me.....

Comment: Have you had a look at what the inner exception is?

Comment: In debug, check the InnerException's Message. Post the message here

Comment: @Fabio Luz  how we get the innerException message........

Comment: i tried this code                                                                                      String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null)
                      ? ex.InnerException.Message
                      : "";                                                                                                         for inner exception but i still contains same message like                      "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. "

Comment: Maybe there is another InnerException inside the InnerException. Run your project in debug mode, simulate the error. A message inside your code will show up. There will be a box, like this one http://csharp.net-informations.com/statements/img/try-catch.png. Click in view details to navigate through the exception object